# Quickest way to get form list item id

Tags: infopath, form, library

I need to know the list item id for an InfoPath form. I have seen solutions to fetch this programmatically, but what is the fastest, easiest way to accomplish this in the browser interface with no code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the integer that is unique to the list (not a GUID), you can simply turn on Inline editing (via the Modify view menu), and mouse over the Edit button you would use to modify the inline list columns.

Your browser should show you the JavaScript link that it references which is something like...

```
javascript: _doPostBack('ctl00%m%g_<GUID>','_cancel;dvt_form_key{<List Item ID>}');
CoreInvoke('ExpGroupOnPageLoad','true');
```

The List Item ID is within the dvt_form_key{} call.

Note: Tested successfully in Firefox and IE

Comment: Thanks, Zork. In this case, I am looking for the list item GUID. Where might I access that?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think there is a way to view the GUID directly from the browser. Possibly using a sharepoint designer workflow you can pull it up, but thats the easiest thing i can give you. Also i have no idea why i didnt just suggest checking ID in the modify view to see normal list ids...